# Unable to install forecast, run meanf

Tags: r

I am trying to run meanf under forecast but I get the following error when I attempt >library(forecast)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘tseries’

I then try to install package 'tseries' and get the following error:

- installing *source* package ‘tseries’ ...
  ** package ‘tseries’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c arma.c -o arma.o
  clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c bdstest.c -o bdstest.o
  clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c boot.c -o boot.o
  gfortran -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c  cfuncs.f90 -o cfuncs.o
  make: gfortran: No such file or directory
  make: *** [cfuncs.o] Error 1
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tseries’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tseries’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tseries’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/kb/zlsmr9016r34v0r8szwknbzh0000gn/T/Rtmp37SuJz/downloaded_packages’

Any help is appreciated on how I can run meanf for a homework assignment.

Comment: You should not need to compile `tseries`. Did you use `install.packages("tseries")`? If asks if you want to install a newer version that requires compiling, just say no. It also looks like you may not have the latest version of R installed. The current version is 4.2.

Comment: Thanks dcarlson! I am new to this and updating to the current version 4.2 helped!! After in installed the newest version there was no questions on whether I even needed to "compile" when i installed "tseries". and now my meanf function works! apologize i didn't even i needed to update as I am doing this for a class. Thanks again